# Title "Rabbi" for Tanoim and Amoroim

Tags: talmud-gemara

Why do we find in the Mishna and Talmud that most תנאים and אמוראים were prefaced with the title "rabbi" but some were not?

Comment: Are you asking about rebbi vs rav, or rebbi/rav vs no title at all?

Comment: IINM רבי always indicates someone who had Semichah, and רב or מר or no title indicates someone who did not. Thus שמואל is never called רבי שמואל because he never received Semichah. I’ll try to get a hard source B”N later - I think it might say this explicitly in regard to Ben Zoma and Ben Azai?

Comment: @DonielF There is also גדול מרבן שמו regarding eg Hillel.

Comment: Most amoraim don't have the title Rabbi

Answer (score 1):

"גדול מרבן - שמו" - קריאת הרב בשמו הפרטי, כגון שמואל הקטן, הלל הזקן וכדומה. המושג מציין כי גדלותו של הרב עולה על התארים האפשריים ואין תואר נוסף לכן יקרא בשמו בלבד. יש לציין כי לא בכל פעם שמוזכר שם של חכם ללא תואר כבוד נובעת העובדה מגדלותו המיוחדת של החכם, כמו במקרה של שמעון בן עזאי או שמעון התימני בו הזכרת שמם ללא תואר כבוד נובעת מכך שהם לא הוסמכו על ידי קודמיהם.

"Greater than Rabban - his name" - calling the rabbi by his first name, such as Shmuel the little, Hillel the Elder and so on. The term indicates that the greatness of the rabbi exceeds the possible degrees and there is no additional title so he will be called by name only. It should be noted that it is not every time that the name of a sage is mentioned without the title of honor stems from the special magnificence of the sage, as in the case of Shimon ben Azzai or Shimon the Yemenite, whose mention without an honorary title stems from the fact that they were not ordained by their predecessors. (Hebrew Wikipedia, תארים רבניים)

Answer (score -1):

In general it goes by eras - the first go without title - Hilel and Shamay, next go with "Rabbi", like Rabbi Yehuda and Rabbi Akiva and Rabbi Yehoshua, Amoroyim started to use Rav (Mar) like Rav Acha or Rav Ashi.

Here's a summary from [Wiki](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%AA%D7%90%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%A8%D7%91%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D#%D7%AA%D7%90%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%A8%D7%91%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%91%D7%A2%D7%91%D7%A8):

```
רבן - נשיא הסנהדרין, בעיקר אלו שהם מצאצאי הלל.
רבי - תואר המקובל לתנא או אמורא שחי ופעל בארץ ישראל.
רב - אמורא שחי ופעל בבבל.
מר - אמורא שחי ופעל בבבל.
```

NB: There are no Amoraim in Mishnah.